# python hex payload into bytearray and convert endianness

Tags: python, arrays, endianness

Hello i am searching for a way to decode a hex coded sensor payload.

The payload is
`payload_hex = "11154c1789870005bd0005bd01000200002900"`
i convert it into an bytearray using.

```
byte = bytearray.fromhex(payload)
decoded = {}
decoded["byte_7"]=byte[7]
decoded["byte_8"]=byte[8]
print(decoded)
```

i am getting for byte_7 = 5 and byte_8 = 189 as a result but that is false the correct numbers would be byte_7 = 1280 and byte_8 = 189. The problem is the endianess. the hex 05 should be 1280 and the hex bd schould be 189.

[image]

Could anyone give me a hint how to make it work in python?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code is doing `0x05 + 0xbd`, which is _not_ the same as `0x05bd`. Similarly, in decimal, `5 + 6` is _not_ `56`

Comment: Hey ForceBru you are totally right but also when i am decoding byte by byte and not adding them i am getting the wrong values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Byte 7 can't be 1280, because *one* byte can only hold numbers from 0 to 255. Hex 05 is just 5, not 1280. Hex 0500, however, is 1280.

You should put the two bytes together like `05bd`, which is done with shifting and ORing:

```
>>> 0x05 << 8 | 0xbd
1469
>>> hex(0x05 << 8 | 0xbd)
'0x5bd'
```

Comment: Thank you. And you are totaly right my mistake.